# How to install/import MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Experts,
I am a newbie, I would like to use MPAndroidChart to plot some line chart.

But I don't know how to install/import it.

Below is what I got so far:

1. I am using Android Studio 2.1.2.
2. I have downloaded 2 files: MPAndroidChart-3.0.0-beta1.tar, MPAndroidChart-3.0.0-beta1.zip from github.

What to do next? (Google results are all about .jar + Eclipse)

Could anyone guide me step by step, operational guide please? Please don't speak alien language.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the dependency in your gradle:

```java
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
}
```

Other ways to use the library can be found [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#usage).

Then import the class:

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
```

Several full examples for various charts, including line chart, can be found [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/d7e659a1fac34f1d187d2ac259a415302ba2cadf/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample).

Comment: So easy? Great! Could you tell me what are the 2 files(.tar,.zip) I downloaded used for?

Comment: ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: I think those .tar and .zip files are the source code. See [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases).